# Importing StarFlut into Android Studio

Tags: python, flutter

I have a python project that webscrapes a website and retrieves data from it. What I want to do now is create an app that when a button is pressed the code within my python project is executed and the website is scraped and the data I need is retrieved. I am working in android studio and using flutter to create this app.

What I have tried to do thus far is look into documentation about how I can implement python into a flutter project. From what I have gathered I use python on the back end and I use a plugin called starflut in order to use python within a flutter project. I've looked into such websites as https://pub.dev/packages/starflut/install, but when I try to perform the first step in cmd I am prompted with the following error: "Expected to find project root in current working directory." I have also looked at the following website as well: https://smazee.com/blog/how-to-run-the-python-code-in-the-flutter-app. I am uncertain about how to do step 2 and the link in step 3 is no longer up. I also saw a post on stackoverflow about this issue, but it seems that they have already installed the plugin. What I want to occur is that by using starflut I can implement the python code I already have display the data within my app. What I am asking for is if anyone knows how to setup this plugin, or knows a good walk through video to watch, or maybe even a better option than to use starflut. From what I have gathered, most of the videos out there are how to USE starflut, not how to INSTALL starflut.